# How to check how much memory is being used for a software and how to increase memory for it?

Tags: ram, crash, memory-usage

Specifically, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and since the Rstudio software gets laggy sometimes, I want to check how much memory is being used for Rstudio and how to grant more memory for it.

How should I do this?

Comment: Add swap space. Use `free` to see RAM & swap. Read `man mkswap swapon fallocate fstab`. Don't create a swapfile with `dd`.

Comment: Could you explain in details how to do that?

Comment: No. Not knowing your system, not knowing your environment,  not knowing what else is running, not wanting to instantiate a "support" relationship with a user desiring a "flip Switch B" type answer, I won't.  Read The Fine Manuals, RTFM.

Comment: Ubuntu has a system monitor application that you can use to monitor memory usage

Answer (score 0):

You don't "grant more memory" to specific applications. The kernel will automatically manage memory for you, and it's quite clever about doing so. Do not try to defeat the kernel

If your system begins to lag, that typically means that your system has exhausted your available memory (RAM) and is swapping pages to storage (disk)...which is much slower, hence the lag.

- Use the shell command `free -h` or your GUI System Monitor application to view a snapshot of your current memory availability.
- Sometimes you can free some additional memory by closing unnecessary applications.
- Sometimes you need more hardware memory.